# Makefile's output explanation

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I wrote the following makefile:

```
MAIN = main
# Macro nome compilatore
CC = gcc
# Macro flag del compilatore
CFLAGS = -Wall
# Macro file oggetto
OBJS = $(MAIN).o
# Macro libreria matematica
LIBS = -lm
# Target
$(MAIN): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) $(LIBS) -o $(MAIN)
```

When i run it for the first time, the output is:

```
gcc -Wall   -c -o main.o main.c
gcc -Wall main.o -lm -o main
```

Can you explain me the first line please? What does it mean?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You did't tell `make` how to make `main.o`, so it used a built-in rule for it and compiled it from `main.c`.

Comment: Hello @HolyBlackCat thank you very much for your explanation. I "copied" the makefile from another more complex makefile; why there is $(MAIN).o instead of $(MAIN).c? If i write, .c it works anyway.

Comment: It doesn't matter in this case. But if you have more than one `.c` file, then building the executable directly from `.c` will require recompiling each one of them even if just one file changes; but if you build object files (`.o`) first, and then link them together as a separate step (like your makefile does), then building the project after changing a single file will only recompile that one file, saving you time.

Comment: Very very clear reply @HolyBlackCat

Comment: Off-topic: That makefile can be written in just three lines by using the built-in rules: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html

Comment: @HolyBlackCat if i create a file.c and if i write gcc -c -o file.c, the compiler doesn't work. How come makefile generates a command line that cannot be executed?

Comment: It's `gcc -Wall -c -o main.o main.c`, you forgot `main.o`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat in this case the -o option should generate an executable file. Why doesn't it happen? Sorry for the nuisance

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi I dont understand your question.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I read in the Dulaney's book that the -o option "Generates the specified output file (used to designate the name of an executable file).". The result of the line gcc -Wall -c -o main.o main.c is the file.o, but it doesn't create an executable file as well. Idem if i write gcc -Wall -c -o main main.o main.c

Comment: It sets the name of the output file, but whether this file will be executable or not depends on other flags. `-c` tells the compiler to generate an object file, and if you don't specify `-c`, it will be an executable. It doesn't matter what extension you specify for the output file.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat fantastic explanation!